# Are there any hidden/random supply crates?

Tags: gears-tactics

In Gears Tactics there are supply crates on the battlefield which when looted hold upgrade items for your squad. I like upgrading my squad so I'd like to go for these crates.

I've only just started playing, and was wondering if I need to be checking all corners of the map for these crates,  or **is there a predetermined spawn for each supply crate?**

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are always 3 crates on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far with my research I've found that:

- each level always includes 3 crates, with predetermined spawn points.
- Rarity of crates increases as the game progresses
  (first levels only have common to rare, then eventually you only find rare, then only rares and epics, etc.)

So it seems that so far, **the crates are *not* randomly distributed, and have predetermined spawns**, and there are always 3.